# Compiler Error C2632: Type 1 followed by Type 2 is illegal

Tags: visual-c++, types

I'm trying to learn an SDK that requires a header file be included. There are two statements in the header file that says

```
typedef long long SomeIdentifier_SInt64;
```

and

```
typedef unsigned long SomeIdentifier_UInt64;
```

The compiler (MSVC++ 6) is complaining that this is illegal.  If so, does this mean the SDK is broken? I seriously doubt this is the case.  Is this legal in other compilers?  Is there any way around this?

Thanks.

My environment is MS Windows XP Pro 32-bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VC6 is too old and too broken to know "long long".  It will compile __int64.  VS200x doesn't have a problem with it.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot replace the software I use at work.  Can I just replace the long long in the header file to __int64? is this considered acceptable practice?

Comment: Depends on your definition of "acceptable". Most people don't consider VC6 acceptable, but if replacing long long with __int64 works, then it's as acceptable as it's going to get.
However, for once VC6 is actually more or less right. long long isn't a valid C++ type. It exists in C, not (yet) in C++

Comment: __int64 *should* work though. On x86, long long is a 64-bit integer. __int64 is simply Microsoft's nonportable name for that datatype.

Comment: Well, my real concern is that I would be modifying an SDK vendor's header file.  Anyway, I guess I will probably have to modify it for now.. Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the February 2003 version of the Platform SDK.

http://blogs.msdn.com/mapo/archive/2007/06/07/last-platform-sdk-compatible-with-visual-studio-6-0.aspx

Comment: Is this not included in SP5 of MSVC6?

Comment: It's quite a big package and I don't know if I have enough resources to download it..

Answer (score 0):

MSVC6 is a pretty old and crappy compiler. Their latest version is much much much (much) better, and you can download it for free on [their website](http://www.microsoft.com/express/download/).

It did support `__int64` and `unsigned __int64` though, so if for some reason you can't use the latest version you can search through the SDK headers and replace every instance of `long long` you find.

Comment: See my comments in nobugz' answer.. Btw, I can't use the express edition, my work requires MFC..